# Printing a line instead of "--------"

Tags: c#, line

For a Windows CE project that we print slips, we have a new request which asks if it is possible to print a line insted of printing "-----------" all the way.

Is this possible without printing an image?

c# / .net 3.5

Thank you

Comment: Underscores generally have no space between them - can't you use them? (They lack centre alignment, of course...)

Comment: @Quppa - we are currently using underscores and you can be sure that they HAVE space between them...

Answer (score 5):

On your desktop run charmap.exe.  Tick "Advanced view" and type "box" in the Search box.  You'll get the Unicode codepoints that you can use to draw lines and boxes.  Copy and paste them into your code.  Whether they actually show up properly on your device depends on the font support.  Odds are decent since they've been around since the first IBM PC. You'll have to try.

Comment: charmap.exe doesn't show the ascii code of "──". I tried directly pasting it but I guess windows ce doesn't support the character.

Comment: Ascii doesn't have codes for these characters, not an issue since .NET uses Unicode.  Charmap shows the Unicode codepoint in the status bar at the bottom of the window when you click a character in the grid.  Other than copy/paste, "\u2500" is the way to get the code for "box drawings light horizontal" into a string.  If you see a rectangle or a diamond with a question mark on the device or the printer (it isn't clear what you use) then the font you use doesn't have a glyph for the codepoint.

Answer (score 3):

There are extendedascii values to do this (196) but it really depends on the printer.

Or as quppa comments use _ but it will not be adequate if you want to box in a title or so.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has an article on [box-drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters).

Since ─ (U+2500) didn't work for you, it's unlikely ━ (U+2501) will work either, but it's perhaps worth a shot. There is also no guarantee that there won't be spaces between these characters, given that spaces appear between underscores.

The issue is not Windows CE supporting Unicode but finding a font that you can use that has the box-drawing characters. Given the likely size limitations (fonts with lots of characters are tens of megabytes big), this might be a challenge.